# Trouble installing rvm on Linux. cURL issue

Tags: ruby, curl, package-managers

I'm trying to get Ruby running on a client's server, and am running up against errors when installing through `yum`.  First, here's our Linux flavor:

```
-sh-3.2$ uname -or
2.6.18-238.12.1.el5 GNU/Linux
```

So, when logged in as a user with sudo privileges, I get this error when running curl:

```
-sh-3.2$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 20511  100 20511    0     0  53522      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  541k
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz
curl: (35) error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '35'.

Downloading https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /data/ftpusers/design/.rvm/
  RVM PATH line found in /data/ftpusers/design/.profile /data/ftpusers/design/.bashrc /data/ftpusers/design/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /data/ftpusers/design/.bash_profile /data/ftpusers/design/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /data/ftpusers/design/.rvm/ is complete.

#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:
```

- No new notes to display.

To complicate things more, I was able to make an install of Ruby from the tarball, but there seem to be libraries missing:

```
-sh-3.2$ gem install compass
 ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Which makes me think I really ought to fix the problem with the package manager, if I can.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with dependencies. Try:

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

and

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

Comment: Thanks @user2546939. Yes, a problem with dependencies. I'm still having trouble getting zlib installed.  When running `rvm pkg install zlib`, it seems to work.  Fetches, Extracts, Configures, Compiles, and Installs. Then I run `rvm reinstall all --force`.  No problems.

Then I exit, log back in, and get them same error:

`ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- zlib `

I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: try:
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Comment: Hi. Not sure if you're still here, but I can't tell if `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` did anything.  `ldd PATH_TO_RUBY_BIN` returned no such file?  Sorry.

Comment: PATH_TO_RUBY_BIN = which ruby

Comment: I don't know if this helps:  

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff32dda000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002afdea866000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002afdeaa81000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002afdeac8a000)
 libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00002afdeae8f000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002afdeb0c7000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002afdeb34a000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002afdea648000)